# Storing API credentials in HTML5 LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, security, local-storage

Is it acceptable to store api credentials for a user client side in HTM5 LocalStorage? It seems secure since LocalStorage is sandboxed by schema:host and obviously client only. What if we also encrypt the api credentials client side before storing in LocalStorage?

Comment: Doesn’t seem that much different from using cookies for the same purpose … but client-side encryption sounds rather useless, because the key would have to be transferred to the client as well at some point. As with cookies, you should not store the actual credentials of the user, but rather a token of some kind that allows access again on a subsequent visit within a reasonable time frame, something server-generated.

Comment: why would a users hard drive be less safe than their screen?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of the API.

The credentials will not be secure from other users with access to the same device.

But if you're working with a scenario which requires zero or only very minimal security requirements, using localStorage could work.

Regarding encryption of the localStorage data -- recognize that you're essentially just obfuscating, not protecting.  Since the encryption key must be passed to the client the best you can hope for is to make it (a little) more difficult to find the API credentials should someone have access to the machine.